# Lookup value by index and name in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a flattened hierarchy:

| Level 1 ID | Level 2 ID | Level 3 ID | Level 4 ID | Name | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | null | null | Finance | Finance |
| 1 | 4 | null | null | Reporting | Finance > Reporting |
| 1 | 4 | 5 | null | Tax Reporting | Finance > Reporting > Tax Reporting |

What I want to do is add or replace with the Level ID columns with 4 Level Name columns based on the Level [] ID columns, like the following:

| Level 1 Name | Level 2 Name | Level 3 Name | Level 4 Name | Name | Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Finance | null | null | null | Finance | Finance |
| Finance | Reporting | null | null | Reporting | Finance > Reporting |
| Finance | Reporting | Tax Reporting | null | Tax Reporting | Finance > Reporting > Tax Reporting |

I would use a separator on the Path column, but in the real dataframe, there are IDs instead of names (formatted like "1 > 4 > 5")

How should I approach this?

Output of `df.info()` is the following:

```
df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 135 entries, 0 to 134
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------      --------------  ----- 
 0   name        135 non-null    object
 1   depid       135 non-null    object
 2   depcode     135 non-null    object
 3   parentpath  135 non-null    object
 4   DEP_LV1_ID  135 non-null    object
 5   DEP_LV2_ID  135 non-null    object
 6   DEP_LV3_ID  98 non-null     object
 7   DEP_LV4_ID  56 non-null     object
dtypes: object(8)
memory usage: 8.6+ KB
```

Comment: "I would use a separator on the Path column, but in the real dataframe, there are IDs instead of names." What does it mean? You have something like "Finance > 4 > 5" in Path column?

Comment: Yes, it's formatted like 1 > 4 > 5. I'll edit the post.

Comment: 1, 4, 5 are strings or integers?

Comment: @Corralien dtypes returns `object`, while trying to change its type says it's `Index`.

Comment: Can you update your post with the output of `df.info()` or the dataframe constructor to make your example reproducible, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping Series to resolve number -> name:

```
url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1-2YXvyb8QEtHrrAO0UCH6vSJ5ww6CCjK&export=download'
df = pd.read_excel(url, index_col=0)

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('DEP_LV\d_ID')]
idx = df[cols].ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1].tolist()

sr = pd.Series(df['name'].tolist(), index=idx)
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: x.map(sr))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                           name  depid depcode         parentpath                 DEP_LV1_ID                                  DEP_LV2_ID                            DEP_LV3_ID     DEP_LV4_ID
0                         Дотоод аудитын хэлтэс    152   61100              |152|      Дотоод аудитын хэлтэс                                         NaN                                   NaN            NaN
1                       Санхүү бүртгэлийн газар    214   31000              |214|    Санхүү бүртгэлийн газар                                         NaN                                   NaN            NaN
2    Хүний нөөцийн бодлого, төлөвлөлтийн хэлтэс    211   32100          |209|211|        Хүний нөөцийн газар  Хүний нөөцийн бодлого, төлөвлөлтийн хэлтэс                                   NaN            NaN
3                      Санхүү бүртгэлийн хэлтэс    215   31100          |214|215|    Санхүү бүртгэлийн газар                    Санхүү бүртгэлийн хэлтэс                                   NaN            NaN
4                           Хүний нөөцийн газар    209   32000              |209|        Хүний нөөцийн газар                                         NaN                                   NaN            NaN
..                                          ...    ...     ...                ...                        ...                                         ...                                   ...            ...
130                               Оёх нэгж (C1)    816   20512  |511|522|811|816|   Үйлдвэр удирдлагын газар                          Сүлжмэлийн үйлдвэр                   Сүлжмэлийн 1-р алба  Оёх нэгж (C1)
131                            Галлериа УБ нэгж    867   11209      |857|859|867|  Дотоод борлуулалтын газар                  Дотоод борлуулалтын хэлтэс                      Галлериа УБ нэгж            NaN
132        Хими цэвэрлэгээ, нөхөн засварын алба    870   11230      |857|859|870|  Дотоод борлуулалтын газар                  Дотоод борлуулалтын хэлтэс  Хими цэвэрлэгээ, нөхөн засварын алба            NaN
133                                 Дархан нэгж    868   11205      |857|859|868|  Дотоод борлуулалтын газар                  Дотоод борлуулалтын хэлтэс                           Дархан нэгж            NaN
134                            Төв дэлгүүр нэгж    869   11201      |857|859|869|  Дотоод борлуулалтын газар                  Дотоод борлуулалтын хэлтэс                      Төв дэлгүүр нэгж            NaN

[135 rows x 8 columns]
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share your data file?

Comment: OK, I'll share in CSV in a few hours when I have access to Gdrive.

Comment: Don't forget to notify me.

Comment: here you go: `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-2YXvyb8QEtHrrAO0UCH6vSJ5ww6CCjK/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=103221979865656183108&rtpof=true&sd=true`

It should be noted that the name column has values in Cyrillic, and the path column has a slightly different formatting - hopefully those won't be a hindrance.

Comment: It worked! What I had to do was to clean up the dataframe a bit - some unavailable values in the hierarchy columns were either `None` or `''`. I replaced either with `np.nan`s with `fillna()` and `replace()`, and that's when your code worked. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The logic is unclear, in particular what is the source of the final values? See two different options below.

###### Assuming the source is `df['Name']`

```
cols = df.filter(like='Level ').columns
names = df['Name'].values
mask = df[cols[:len(names)]].notna()

df[cols[:len(names)]] = mask.mul(names, axis=1).where(mask)
```

Output:

```
  Level 1 ID Level 2 ID     Level 3 ID  Level 4 ID           Name                                 Path
0    Finance        NaN            NaN         NaN        Finance                              Finance
1    Finance  Reporting            NaN         NaN      Reporting                  Finance > Reporting
2    Finance  Reporting  Tax Reporting         NaN  Tax Reporting  Finance > Reporting > Tax Reporting
```

###### If you rather want to extract from "Path"

```
cols = df.filter(like='Level ').columns
names = df['Path'].str.split(' > ', expand=True)

df.loc[:, cols[:names.shape[1]]] = names.to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
  Level 1 ID Level 2 ID     Level 3 ID  Level 4 ID           Name                                 Path
0    Finance       None           None         NaN        Finance                              Finance
1    Finance  Reporting           None         NaN      Reporting                  Finance > Reporting
2    Finance  Reporting  Tax Reporting         NaN  Tax Reporting  Finance > Reporting > Tax Reporting
```

###### reproducible input:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy import nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'Level 1 ID': [1, 1, 1],
                   'Level 2 ID': [nan, 4.0, 4.0],
                   'Level 3 ID': [nan, nan, 5.0],
                   'Level 4 ID': [nan, nan, nan],
                   'Name': ['Finance', 'Reporting', 'Tax Reporting'],
                   'Path': ['Finance', 'Finance > Reporting', 'Finance > Reporting > Tax Reporting']}
                 )
```

Comment: `df['Path'].str.split(' > ', expand=True).reindex(columns=range(4)).fillna('').rename(columns=lambda x: f'Level {x+1} Name')`

Comment: @Corralien I thought of something like this but this relies on the proper format of the columns. But yes, this should work as well ;)

Comment: @mozway Thank you. I should have mentioned that the number of records is 135 in this case, not 3. 

The following is returned: `ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series, length must be 4: given 135`.

Comment: which line triggers the error? My code should automatically handle the number of columns if there is at least as many "Level X ID" than max number of items in "Path"

Comment: @mozway The last line with the `mask.mul` returns the error. I wondered if it was a data type issue and tried converting the Level x columns into type `int` with `cols = df.filter(like='Level ').columns.astype(int)`, to which it returned the error `TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype int32`. I still wonder if wrong column data type is the issue.

Comment: I have updated the post with `df.info()` if that helps.

Comment: @sokhymi please an example that fails in the form of a DataFrame constructor for reproducibility (see my updated answer, I added a DataFrame constructor).

Comment: OK, I tried your dataframe in my environment and it works. But I noticed that in my actual dataframe, some empty entries are not "null" - I'll see to converting them, see if that's the problem, then get back here.

Comment: @mozway Corralien's solution worked for me. Previously, it did return the aforementioned `ValueError` for their code as well, but converting `None` and `''` values to `np.nan` and executing their code worked. I tried your solution afterwards too, on the dataframe with NaNs, but it still returns the `ValueError`. I assume, maybe something wrong with the `.notna()` function? Thank you, regardless!